# Find a regular homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

Firstly, we define a regular homotopy between regular closed curves as a continuous map $F: I \times I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the following conditions:

(i) for each fixed $u \in I$, the map $\gamma_{u}(t)=F(u,t)$ is a regular closed curve.

(ii) All derivatives $\gamma_{u}^{(k)}(t)$ (with respect to $t$) depend continuously on $u$.

So here's the question:

> Let $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $\gamma(t)=((1+2 \cos(t) ) \cos(t) , (1+2 \cos(t) ) \sin(t))$. By finding
>   a suitable regular homotopy compute the rotation index of the curve. You also need to justify the regularity of your homotopy.

Now, I know that if 2 curves are regularly homotopic, then they have the same rotation index, and to check regularity I must check that the derivative never vanishes.  But I am a little unsure of how to find a regular homotopy.

My first thoughts involved splitting up the function into $$\gamma(t)=(\cos(t) , \sin(t) ) +(2\cos^{2}(t), 2\cos(t) \sin(t) ).$$
And then perhaps trying $$F(u,t) =(\cos(t) , \sin(t) )+(1-u)(2\cos^{2}(t), 2\cos(t) \sin(t) ) \ ?$$
Or maybe $$F(u,t) =(1-u)(\cos(t) , \sin(t) )+(2\cos^{2}(t), 2\cos(t) \sin(t) ) \ ?$$

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I like your attempts at the homotopy. The simplest curve — one whose rotation index you can easily see — is a reasonable goal for the other end of your homotopy. But you need to address the differentiability condition, and think about regularity of each intermediate curve.

Comment: So, trying my first idea, and using F(u,t)=(cost,sint)+(1-u)(2cos$^{2}$t, 2costsint) I find $F'(u,t)=(-sint,cost)+(1-u)(-4costsint, 2cos2t).  Where would I go from here?

Comment: The final answer is that the rotation index is 2.  Can't see at all how this is though!..

Comment: Yup, it's true, so that shows that our homotopy $F$ cannot be a regular homotopy. Clearly you should try to homotop to the other factor, since it will have a rotation index of $2$ :)

Comment: But how would I know that my initial attempt was not correct?? I only know from looking at the answer.

Comment: Because it evidently is *not* a regular homotopy!! Do you have a program like Mathematica (or Sage or Maple) that will allow you to draw pictures? You can graph the homotopy as a movie and watch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you've settled on $F(u,t) = (\cos t,\sin t) + 2(1-u)(\cos^2t,\cos t\sin t)$. To me it is evident that this is a smooth (infinitely differentiable) function of $t$ and $u$. What you really need to check is that $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t} \ne 0$ for every value of $t$ and $u$. This is the regularity condition for the curve $\gamma_u$. It might help to write 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (u,t)= (-\sin t,\cos t) + 2(1-u)(-\sin 2t,\cos 2t)$$
and think a bit. Are these two vectors ever parallel?

Here's a picture of $\gamma$ for you, so you can verify that the rotation index is actually $2$.

[image: Twice-turning curve]

For the homotopy you had, to turn a circle into this curve, one must introduce a cusp or kink when the second loop is born (thinking in reverse time here):

[image]

Comment: By 'these two vectors' do you mean F and its differential?  I can't see that these would ever be parallel. Does this make it a regular homotopy?  Thanks.

Comment: No, I mean the two vectors in the formula above for $\partial F/\partial t$. If you allow a non-regular homotopy, you can turn a wind into a kink and then make it disappear, thus altering the rotation index.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to any sort of program that can help me visualize this, so I'm just trying to learn the method here.  So there must be some point (u,t) where the differential disappears then?  What point is this? Can't see it

Comment: Try $u=1/2$ and $u=\pi$.

Comment: Thank you. You've been most helpful! Just another quick question, when looking at the diagram you have kindly supplied, how does one know the sign of the rotation index?  I.e. which direction is the curve traversed, so I'd know that it was 2, and not -2, just from observing an image.

Comment: You can't. You have to watch which direction the parametrization sends you on the curve. This is easy by looking at the velocity vectors from our earlier derivative calculation. I've added more, BTW. Feel free to accept the answer when you're happy :)